# Randomly varying behaviour on "self" access from a module in ActiveRecord-Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to hunt down a bug in an application which has been running for about 5 years now, it's still on Rails 2.3.18 and Ruby 1.8.7, so I'm not sure whether this observation is still relevant in more recent versions.

After some analysis, I've found that the bug is clearly not reproducible and its occurency varies from server-restart to server-restart. Once it's there and once it's not. I have observed it while using webrick on a local machine and with passenger and apache on the production environment. As I don't see any pattern which preceedes it's occurrence, it maybe could be kind of a race condition or something alike. It happens under all environments I've tried it with (Ubuntu, Fedora, Windows). But as far as I can remember (unfortunately I can't verify that anymore) it started to appear after upgrading to Rails 2.3.* from something 2.0.*.

Here's the setting:

- The module named "**Measurable**" assumes that the surrounding class has a field named "unit" and a field named "**count**" which stores an integer value.
- There is an abstract class named "**Unit**" which has specific implementations which are "Kilogram", "Piece" etc.
- There is an ActiveRecord-classs named "**OrderArticle**" which has the integer fields named "unit" and "count" and includes the module "Measurable".

And here's what's happening:

1. An instance of OrderArticle is created by the input of some form data but not yet saved.
2. To do some price calculations, a method from the module Measurable is called:

   ```
   def lot
     return Unit.get_instance(self.unit, self.count)
   end
   ```
3. This method calls the following method in the Unit-factory class:

   ```
   def self.get_instance(constant, count=0)
     if constant.nil?
       raise 'nil is invalid as unit constant!'
     end

     constant = constant.to_i
     count = count.to_f
     klass = class_for(constant)
     return klass.new(count)
   end
   ```

And that's it. Sometimes (according to my observations, I'd say most times), everything works fine. But some other times, `self.unit` seems to be `nil` upon calling the `Unit.get_instance` method.

And the only change to get out of that again is to restart the server (webrick or apache with mod_passenger).

Has anybody ever seen something like that? Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

EDIT: Here is the code for the `class_for` method:

```
def self.class_for(constant)
  if constant == Gram.representation
    return Gram
  elsif constant == Kilogram.representation
    return Kilogram
  else
    return Piece
  end
end
```

Comment: I seem to be missing a definition for "class_for" as well. What's the source code for that?

Comment: I'm guessing you end up with string objects as "constant" ? I'm surprised that you have all this tight coupling in there. OrderArticle calls a method from Measurable which refers to Unit? You need to bring that stuff out into a helper object. That's got an 80% chance of fixing your problem by removing random state.

Comment: No, as far as I found out, the "constant" either is an integer (which it should be) when called by the method "lot" when everything works fine or it is "nil" when something doesn't. And both variations occur on the same test cases. But I agree, the tight coupling is indeed very ugly.

Comment: Could it be that the `self.unit` field in the `OrderArticle` class might not have a value sometimes when it get's read by the `lot` method from the contained module?

Comment: Is "Gram.representation" a number? Whoa. Talk about implicit inheritance. Anyway, since the problem is "nil", it seems like the error has to happen _before_ "lot" is called, so ... what does the code that calls "lot" look like? (I'm probably going to want to backtrack this all the way to the controller).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using threads, as that code doesn't look thread safe?

You are calling a method on a module, and that module could be shared across multiple threads.

I'd suggest turning Unit into a class:

```
class Unit
attr_reader :constant, count

  def initialize(constant, count = 0)
    @constant = constant
    @count = count
  end

  def get_instance
    if constant.nil?
      raise 'nil is invalid as unit constant!'
    end

    constant = constant.to_i
    count = count.to_f
    klass = class_for(constant)
    return klass.new(count)
  end
end
```

And then modify your lot method to:

```
def lot
  measurement_unit = Unit.new(unit, count)
  measurement_unit.get_instance
end
```

That way, the get_instance method code is applied within an individual Unit instance, rather than a shared module.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! That's definitely worth a try, although I don't use threads explicitely in that application. But I also think that upon calling the `lot` method from the `Measurement` module, the field `unit` in the calling class sometimes has a value and sometimes is nil.